# AOT (Ahead-Of-Time) Compilation with ES5

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, babeljs, ecmascript-5

Is it possible to do AOT compilation in Angular using only ES5?

More to the point, can I use the [NGTools Webpack plugin](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/%40ngtools/webpack) with ES5?

I know TypeScript is the preferable language of choice for Angular, however my place of employment did not approve using TypeScript for our Angular project.  My hands are a bit tied, and I don't want performance to suffer on the client due to this.

**Some relevant info on my project:**

- Webpack 2 for build/packaging
- Written in ES2015 transpiled to ES5 using Babel

I have looked all over and have not been able to find a clear answer on this, I would really appreciate any info anyone can provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is incorrect per se. 'Written in ES2015 transpiled to ES5 using Babel' is not equal to 'ES5'. Still,currently not possible any way.

Answer (score 5):

In you tsconfig.json file set the target to es5.

```
    "target": "es5",
```

Comment: AOT compiler will only compile typescript.

Answer (score 3):

Angular is *supposed* to be fully ES5 compatible.

The AOT compiling process uses the *metadata* attached to components. This is how it finds the templates and styles that need compiling.

TypeScript is the preferred method for writing components. As it allows you to use the `@Component` annotation function to attach metadata .

ES6 is secondary method and Angular supports ES6 decorators to attach metadata to components.

ES5 is more basic. There isn't any automatic way to attach metadata, but the AOT compiler will look for a `annotations` array attached to the object's prototype.

This is how you would do it using ES5

```
HeroComponent.annotations = [
     new ng.core.Component({
        selector: 'hero-view',
        template: '<h1>{{title}}: {{getName()}}</h1>'
     })
];
```

So to answer your question. *Yes*, you can still use AOT with ES5.

Comment: https://aio-staging.firebaseapp.com/guide/ts-to-js#aot-compilation-in-typescript-only

Comment: @yurzui So are you implying what ThinkingMedia provided is incorrect?  In your link it is mentioned, "AOT is not an option for pure JavaScript applications at this time".

Comment: Well that sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your original code is ES2015 what you can do is to use the AOT compiler directly on your ES2015 JavaScript code. Where you have used decorators on the classes. 
You can compile to ES5 directly from the AOT compiler without using Babel first. Most angular libraries have also the ES5 target to be compatible also with older browsers.
To do this you set the already mentioned setting in tsconfig.json

```
"target": "es5",
```

Check also the official article about AOT. [AOT Compiler](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

The AOT compiler is essentially a typescript compiler with additional features it will work also with JavaScript. JavaScript code is also valid in TypeScript. Look at the first example on the TypeScript tutorial. [TypeScript in 5 minutes](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html)

I have experimented a bit with this and for me it works if I change the .js files to .ts without changing the code. The TypeScript compiler has also an option to support .js files.

```
"allowJs": true,
```

From my tests it looks like the AOT compiler ignores that because i got errors if i used .js files so i think you need to rename the files to .ts as i mentioned before. I was testing with the NGTools webpack plugin.

If you still want to use Babel for the ES5 conversion you can set the target of the typescript/AOT compiler to ES2015 so the output will still be ES2015 code and then feed it to Babel after the AOT compilation.